# jquery cycle plugin using RSS feed images?

Tags: jquery, drupal, rss, cycle

This could well be a terribly ignorant question, if so please forgive me:

I'm using jquery cycle plugin to create an image rotator of recently posted images.

Im using drupal 6.x and created an RSS feed of the recent images using the views module. I have no idea how to connect the two. Any suggestions?

I have a feeling an RSS feed might not be the best way to go about this, but it's all I could come up with.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Views Slideshow:

http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

I've used this in the past to show a picture, wait, then fade to the next picture.  It's an output type for a view.  Totally point & click, no coding. I just made a CCK content type holding the images, then made a a view just showing whatever I wanted to show, and a in the slideshow output options in the view set to fade after a specific delay.  Dead easy and sweet.  I might yet be able to wean my clients off using a flash splash page. ;-)

or Views Carousel is a different feature set if you want to show several at the same time and have it auto advance.

Andy-